# libgdx textfield language on Android

Tags: android, input, textfield, libgdx

How to get input into libgdx TextField in native language on Android? 
I mean an ability to input login or password for example. Yes, i could call smth like `Gdx.input.getTextInput` or native Android dialog, but it's really awful.

My code sample:

```
TextField loginField = new TextField("",getSkin());
loginField.setText("sdfdfsdаыва");
```

Text in the field is drawn well with `setText()`, i.e. skin font contains all required glyphs. But on Android (emulator & physical) i can't input any native character.

Answer (score 2):

For user's text inputs using short alphabets like Latin and Cyrillic, you can use the LibGDX FreeTypeFontGenerator & FreeTypeFontParameter :

```
private BitmapFont yourCustomFont;
private FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
private FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;
private TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle;
private TextField textField;

...

public void show(){

    ...

    // Font generating

    yourCustomFont = new BitmapFont();
    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(
            Gdx.files.internal("yourFont.ttf"));
    parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();

    // Complete the following sequence with the letters you need(each only once)
    parameter.characters =
    "БбДдЄєabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUXYZ/&1234567890()[]#'\"";

    parameter.size = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 20);
    yourCustomFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose(); //Don't forget to dispose the generator

    // TextFieldStyle
    textFieldStyle = new TextFieldStyle();
    textFieldStyle.font = yourCustomFont;
    textFieldStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;

    // TextField
    textField = new textField("",textFieldStyle);
    textField.setTextFieldListener(new TextFieldListener() {

         public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char key) {

        }
    });

    ...

}
```

For user's text inputs using complex alphabets like Chinese,Korean or Japanese, you may need to use a pre-rendered font in .fnt + .png format. 
To do that you can use softwares like Hiero or BMFont.

http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/

http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero

Complex alphabets (Korean,Japanese,Chinese...) generated with Hiero or BMFont are big size files, so you may need to load them with the LibGdx AssetManager. Then use the font with your TextFieldStyle, the same way as previously described.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT :**
Now, LibGDX can render complex glyphes on the fly :
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype